# JavaFx: How to develop a visual rich menu interface?

Tags: interface, menu, javafx

I'm trying to develop a desktop program, unifying java and javafx.

For now, I want to know recommendations about how to create a rich menu interface for my program, something like the menu of Office 2007 or Modellus.

So, what you recommend to start developing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what level of experience you have with JavaFX, but if it's limited, then start with the tutorials at [javafx.com](http://javafx.com), and similar on the web (see [Jim Weaver's site](http://learnjavafx.typepad.com/)).

From there I think your best bet would be to find similar open source applications and learn from those.  Frankly I think it won't be easy because there's not a great deal of similar applications out there to learn from.

However you could take a look at [Project MaiTai](http://www.projectmaitai.org/), [MusicExplorer](http://musicexplorerfx.citytechinc.com/) for starters.

Comment: I thought there was some technology associated with JavaFx that could help me building that kind of menu. Thank you, anyway. I'll start from tutorials, and try to make a mix of Swing and JavaFx, doing whatever is possible.

Comment: Take a look also at jfxtras.org - it might not have specific menu type stuff, but some of the available components might help you on your way.